# In what way were David's descendants kohanim? (2 Samuel 8:18 וּבְנֵי דָוִד, כֹּהֲנִים הָיוּ)

Tags: words, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-david

In [2 Samuel 8:18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08b08.htm#18) it says:

> VeBnei David kohanim hayu

English translations translate the word kohanim as "chief ministers" or such titles.

Any clarification? I'm confused since only Aaron's descendants are allowed to be kohanim.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, most (if not all) commentators explain that *kohanim* means high-ranking, respected, people.

One useful tool is comparing *psukim* from these times with their equivalents in Divrei Hayamim, which in this case ([Divrei Hayamim 1, 18, 17](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t25a18.htm)) quotes the *passuk* almost word for word (translation from [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16538)):

> וּבְנֵי-דָוִיד הָרִאשֹׁנִים, לְיַד הַמֶּלֶךְ ...
>   
> ... and the sons of David were first at the king's hand.